# Selecting Specific Information Using Two Tables

Tags: sql, ms-access-2000

I have two tables:

**Players**

```
Player_id
email_address
highest_level
```

**Login**

```
login_id
ip_address
player_id
login_date
login_time
```

I'm looking to count the number of distinct logins per player, but only for login date `2014-06-01` and only for player email addresses ending in `.net`.

I know how to do these things individually, but I'm struggling to put it all together.  I'm stuck between using `JOIN` or `IN` and how exactly to set it up.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment.  Have you attempted anything?

Comment: Yes, I just couldn't remember how to do the JOIN.  I knew the WHERE email LIKE '*.net', filtering the dates WHERE login_date = '2014-06-01', and to count(*).  I just needed refreshing my memory on joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
SELECT p.Player_id,COUNT(*) FROM PLAYERS p
INNER JOIN LOGIN l ON p.Player_id = l.Player_id
WHERE l.login_date = '2014-06-01' AND l.email_address LIKE '%.net'
GROUP BY p.Player_id
```

Sorry, i forget group by.. now i added.